# How To Parameter Array To The Function In Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to assign a value to the array I gave as a parameter as follows. But I am not getting the array correctly. I tried to send the array as a parameter with the following method.

```
Func()
{
  parameter=$1
  echo $parameter
  for ((i = 0; i < 26; i++)); do
    parameter[$i]=0
  done
}
Func "${array_kelime1[@]}"
```

Comment: `$1` is only the _first_ part of the array. The rest of it goes in `$2` and onward. Each array element becomes a separate argument.

Comment: what should i do @CharlesDuffy

Comment: If your goal is to _modify_ the array, use a namevar (`declare -n parameter=$1`), and pass `Func array_kelime1`. Note that this requires a modern bash release (I don't remember if they were introduced in 4.1 or 4.3, but something in that range -- it's a feature not available in the 3.x release MacOS ships).